# How can I prevent an ActiveRecord object's fields from being changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3 project, I have a table that I want to only be for reference to the application: I *never* want anyone to have the ability to change this data within the app. Here's what I have so far:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_readonly :name, :description

  has_many :bars

  def readonly?
    return true
  end
  ...
end
```

While this prevents saving the record or using `update_attributes`, I'd like to lock it down even more: is there a way for me to prevent assignment of a loaded record, a la:

```
f = Foo.find(1)
f.name = 'New Name'
SomeError: You cannot change properties of this object
```

Comment: Why is it an active record object?

Comment: Because the original configuration of the object is in the database. Long story.

Comment: Why do you want to stop the altering of attributes? If they can't save them, why does it matter?

Comment: It probably doesn't, but I'm curious to know how hard I can lock these suckers down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a custom setter for the property:

```
def name=(val)
  raise RuntimeError, 'You cannot change properties of this object'
end
```

This will prevent anyone from modifying the value.